# 'setup.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - Visual Studio Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

I am creating a setup file in visual studio in which I have to install external application in silent mode. In custom action i add cmd.exe in commit section and in argument i write 
**/c cmd.exe /c "[TARGETDIR]Utility/InstallOnly.bat"**.

But after installation of main application i got error on command prompt

**'setup.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**

[setup file system screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmOCI.png)

in custom action

[Custom Actions screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tywK1.png)

Here's the script of batch file

***@echo off
setup.exe /s /v "/qn /l*v %temp%\ururte_install.log"
REM Pass /norestart to the msiexec command to disable reboot after 
REM installation.
@pause
REM this batch file will perform a silent install***

Please tell me what's wrong i have done.

Comment: What's in your batch file? Are you sure the working directory is correct when it is trying to run the setup program?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes all files are there. If I run the batch file directly then installation will start perfectly. Let me add script of batch file in my question.